# Simple heat equation with exponential reaction term

Tags: differential-equations

This is the heat equation that i want to solve
$${\partial T\over\partial t}={{1\over r^2}{\partial\over \partial r}(r^2{\partial T\over \partial r})+qAC_0exp(-E_a/RT) } \ \ \ 0<t<10, \ \ \ 0<r<1 $$
$$T(0,r)=293,\ \ \   T(t,1)=308, \ \ \ \ \ {\partial T\over \partial r}(t,0)=0 $$

```
NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] == 
   D[u[t, x], x, x] + (2/x)*D[u[t, x], x] + 8100*3.15*0.3*Exp[-720/(8.314*u[t, x])], 
  u[0, x] == 293, u[t, 1] == 308, D[u[t, 0], x] == 0}, 
  u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 1}
]
```

then this error occurred:

[image: .]

How can i modify this code?